# Not showing notification when I got new badge

Tags: discussion, bug

I am suffering from this issue before but I don't mind and think this is my misunderstanding but this time I'm looking for this that my SO account doesn't show me notification when I got any badge I have some proof for this...

**This image showing that I got this badge 53 min before and now the second one....**

[image]

**And here this is showing I didn't got any of badge today....**

[image]

Is this a bug or what ? why don't I got the notification for badges

Comment: Its mean its a cache problem

Comment: You are considered a *veteran* and are not notified of every little bronze badge anymore. This is by design.

Comment: Also note that the same happens [for privileges](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/why-doesnt-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top-notify-me-if-i-earn-a-privilege) too!