# Achievements menu no longer shows new privileges earned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, achievements-dialog

I remember in the past (and the menu's tooltip still says so) that I would get a notification in my Achievements menu whenever I reached a new privilege level thanks to reputation gains, like 100, 500, 1000, etc. However, for a while now (at least 2500, 3000, and 5000), I haven't received any of those notifications:

[image]

As you can see, I recently got enough rep to send me over 5,000 for the first time, but there's nothing mentioned about the associated privileges (approve tag wiki edits) I've earned. Checking the Privileges page, however, shows that I have in fact earned it, so it isn't a case of waiting for a server to syncing or anything, like with badges and review flags.

What gives? Was this feature removed intentionally? Or is it a bug?

**EDIT**: This appears to be intentional, as per the answer given at **[Why doesn't the reputation tab at the top notify me if I earn a privilege?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/why-doesnt-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top-notify-me-if-i-earn-a-privilege)**

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I got tag creation not long ago, with zero fanfare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/why-doesnt-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top-notify-me-if-i-earn-a-privilege). And this also [happens for badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283251/not-showing-notification-when-i-got-new-badge)

Comment: @CoolGuy Well, that's kind of whack. "We'll notify you if you hit 1500 rep and can now add tags... unless you've hit 200 rep and gotten the association bonus on another site already, in which case you're a veteran and clearly don't need the notification!"

Comment: @CoolGuy That doesn't appear to be the issue here. He claims that he didn't get notifications for the privileges at 2500 and 3000, which are both set to true for notifying veterans. If he were only claiming he didn't get the notification for 5000, then that would make more sense.

Comment: I was also under the impression that the privilege notifications worked slightly different from the badge notifications, in that you could not be considered veteran for a privilege until you've received the notification for it *at least once* on any site on the network.

Comment: @animuson, You have a point there. But I believe it is exaggeration. I don't think that the OP remembers if he did/did not get the notification at 3K and 2.5K rep.

Comment: @CoolGuy "you don't think"?  why not?

Comment: @eis , because its probably weeks(or a month or more) ago that the OP acquired 2.5K or 3K rep. The OP will remember that he got notification for at least **a** privilege he has earned,but will not be sure if he has been notified for **every** privilege he has earned till date. Even I wasn't sure about this when I did not get a notification for a privilege I've earned some weeks ago. We can ask the OP about this once he is online.

Comment: Hmm, I see; it's most likely the veteran thing at play here. That's pretty lame, though, because some people *do* like to see that. Continued positive affirmation that you're "playing the game" correctly. @CoolGuy You're correct; I can't recall with perfect clarity whether I got previous notifications or not. Though I have to wonder why the 5k rep perk alone is set to "False" among all the other high-rep perks. It really should be a user's choice. 

If a moderator could re-tag this with `status-bydesign`, that'd be nice.

Comment: Not 100% sure off the top of my head how this works... that is, if this *is* by design or if the design needs to be adjusted. Or if, indeed, we have good intentions but also a bug. ;) Let's not rush to retag it as status-anything so that we can look into it more internally later.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'll certainly take that :-) Thanks

Comment: @TylerH ,I thought so! BTW, should I post the answer in the duplicate post here?

Comment: @CoolGuy Feel free, but in light of Adam's comment, I will leave the question open for a response from the moderation team/the StackOverflow team.

Comment: @AdamLear Any word on if this is a bug or is it [status-bydesign]?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is by design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151677/did-not-get-notification-about-new-privilege/151679#151679

Comment: @TylerH Cool.  Thanks.  I'll be using this as a dupe target so it would be nice to get the tag added

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, seems to be by design. Whether it's *good* design is a different question. :) Maybe something along the lines of at least waiting until someone has received all privileges at least once... I don't have a read on how easy it'd be to implement something like that, though.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for the info.  That would be cool if you could do that as you would at least get one notification for each privileged.  Would you mind marking this [status-bydesign]?

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting this answer so that this question can be used as a dupe target)

This appears to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151677/did-not-get-notification-about-new-privilege/151679#151679) (Meta.SE link).

From the post:

> You won't get notification because you are considered a "Veteran user", such users get fewer notifications.
>
> A veteran is a user with an associated account (on the site that was associated). If you click associate account on meta and its associated to SO, your meta account is veteran.