# No notification of getting the "approve tag wiki edits" privilege

Tags: bug

I got the privilege of approving tag wiki edits today. However, I did not get a notification about it. (This was in the morning.)

It's not visible in the Achievements menu, either.

Comment: IIRC the scripts to push privilege notifications runs like once or twice a day (it's been a while since I've received another privilege).  I'd give it 24 hours.

Comment: @NathanOliver Strange, because i distinctly remember getting a notification in an hour when I got my last few privileges.

Comment: Well, I could be recalling incorrectly ;)

Comment: Just found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284382/achievements-menu-no-longer-shows-new-privileges-earned) which links to [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/why-doesnt-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top-notify-me-if-i-earn-a-privilege) which says this is one of those things they don't tell you about anymore.

Comment: The strange thing is that I actually got a notification about getting the 10k privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@NathanOliver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver), I just found out that I am a veteran user [according to SE](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/why-doesnt-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top-notify-me-if-i-earn-a-privilege) and I won't receive notifications about privileges anymore. Cool!